# Use ASP.Net insert command to apply on an ORACLE database table

Tags: asp.net, oracle

Good day! I'm trying to insert just an entity to a single field in an ORACLE database table but I'm having this error in my Stack Trace:

```
**Stack Trace**:
```

> [OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
>   ]
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException.Check(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc) +338968
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName) +879
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions) +129
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject) +40
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +31
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +548
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +69
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +470
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +118
>      System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open() +43
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +378
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +399
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource.Insert() +19
>      ASP.jtrap_import_aspx.InsertWeight(Object Source, EventArgs e) in E:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\jTRAP_net v1\jTRAP_net\jTRAP_import.aspx:12
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628722
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Here is my **data source**:

```
<asp:Sqldatasource
ID="OracleServer1" Runat="server" 
ConnectionString="Data Source=OracleServer1;Persist Security Info=True;"
ProviderName="System.Data.OracleClient"
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO tbl_object(WEIGHT) VALUES(@Weigh)">
      <insertparameters>
        <asp:formparameter name="Weigh" formfield="TextBox1" />            
      </insertparameters>
</asp:Sqldatasource>
```

And here is my **connection string** located in my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>

 <add name="OracleConnectionString" 
  connectionString="Data Source=OracleServer1;Persist 
  Security Info=True;" 
  providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" 
/>
```

Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, then your connect string does not match the TNS entry on your machine.  What happens when to try ti TNSPING OracleServer1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a better choice of doing it in the code behind as I'm more familiar w/ this method and made it work:

code behind:

```
    Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("OracleConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim oracleConnection As New Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(strConnection)

    If oracleConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        MsgBox("Opening oracle connection")
        oracleConnection.Open()
        MsgBox("Oracle connection successfully opened.")
    End If


    Dim strQuery As String = "INSERT INTO ......(so on)"
    Dim oracleCommand As New OracleCommand(strQuery, oracleConnection)

    MsgBox("Inserting values to the table")

    oracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Successfully inserted values into the table")
```

And here's my connection string code in the web.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="OracleConnectionString" 
  connectionString="Data Source=localhost;USER ID=username;PASSWORD=password" 
  providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" 
/>  </connectionStrings>
```